# CSS: Merging borders with rounded elements using border radius

Tags: html, css

I got a mockup for something that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can make this without using images using CSS3?  The border-around-a-border thing with rounded corners seems to be not possible to do...  The part with the gray background having rounded bottom borders seems to also make things more difficult, since otherwise it could just not have borders.  Note that the border should not be any wider when they come together, they are supposed to be 2px everywhere.

Comment: sure it can! with a container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negative margins! [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGBHY/2/)

#### HTML

```
<section>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    content
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
section, h1 {
    border: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 8px;
}

h1 {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    margin: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px; 
}
```

Comment: So much for writing my answer listing the steps in English. +1

Answer (score 1):

And another: http://jsfiddle.net/zv3tw/1/ ;-)

Here I've included the bottom left and right border to be not rounded as per your mock.

```
#container
{
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    height:120px;
}

#header{
    height:30px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}

#header, #container
{
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't cut it, the bottom border of the header is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5mcv/1/). The borders are black because the rounded corners are hard to see at `#ccc`.

#### HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div#outer
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

div#outer div
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background: #eee;
    font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
}
```